# Overflow with CSS, need sometimes a scrollbar and sometimes not (overlay box) dynamical screenheight

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overflow

i've a problem with height:auto and overflow:auto;.

I've created a overlay with dynamical content. Sometimes the content leaves the visible screen and then a scrollbar should be shown to prevent cutting the content. My bad looking solution is setting height to 100% that fills the screen with a empty white area. If the height is missing or not set all browsers arn't able to reconize that the acp_message should have a scrollbar

How to be sure that the scrollbar will be shown if height is auto?

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    var id;
   $('.order_options').on('click', 'span', function (e) {
   //$('#activator').click(function(){  
            $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast',function(){
                $('#box').animate({'top':'60px'},500);          
                $('#box').css('height', '100%');
                //$('#box').css('height', 'auto');
                $('#acp_message').css('margin-bottom', '250px');
                //$('#box').css('margin-bottom', '30px');
            }); 
        set_rechnung_erstellen(e.target.id);

    });
});
```

now the css:

```
.overlay {
    background:transparent url(../image/overlay.png) repeat top left;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    z-index:100;
}
.box {
    position:fixed;
    top:-200px;
    left:30%;
    right:30%;
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#7F7F7F;
    padding:20px;
    border:2px solid #ccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    -khtml-border-radius:20px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #333;
    z-index:101;
    /*height:auto;*/
    /*height: expression(document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.offsetHeight ? document.body.scrollHeight : document.body.offsetHeight + 'px');*/
}
.box h1{
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #7F7F7F;
    margin:-20px -20px 0px -20px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#FFEFEF;
    color:#EF7777;
    -moz-border-radius:20px 20px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}
.
#acp_message {
   overflow:auto;
}
```

and finally the HTML

```
<div class="box" id="box" style="overflow:auto;">
 <a class="boxclose" id="boxclose">Schlie&szlig;en</a>
 <h1>Rechnung erstellen</h1>
 <p id="acp_message">
  Rechnung erstellen
 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: i dont see any overlay div n what should be scrollable for dynamic content the msg or the complete overlay??

Comment: Now it works. i've added the complete Markup. the "box" is outside of the screen, if you lunch your browser. oh! your right! will edit the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have a `.` before your rule for `#acp_message`. This will break that rule, so make sure that is not in your code.

Secondly, use a max-height and overflow:auto to do what you are looking for. And these have to both be applied to the same element:

```
.box { height: auto; max-height:100%; overflow:auto; }
```

If you want to get the exact height of the screen and apply it in jQuery, you can do that as well:

```
$('.box').css('max-height', $(window).height() + 'px');
```

Comment: It is confusing i tried it today again, with your solution it works with max-height:100% ...